# How do I add a "last updated" column in a SQL Server 2008 R2 table?

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in my SQL Server 2008 R2 database, and would like to add a column called LastUpdated, that will automatically be changed every time the row is updated. That way, I can see when each individual row was last updated.

It seems that SQL Server 2008 R2 doesn't have a data type to handle this like earlier versions did, so I'm not sure of the best way to do it. I wondered about using a trigger, but what would happen when the trigger updated the row? Will that fire the trigger again, etc?

Comment: Are you thinking of `timestamp`? This is nothing to do with date/time and now called `rowversion`

Comment: What data type handled this in earlier versions? If you're thinking of `TIMESTAMP` or `ROWVERSION` you'd be wrong - this column does not contain date/time information and can't be used to determine "last updated"...

Comment: I was thinking of timestamp/rowversion, which I thought was to do with dates when I posted. I've since discovered that it never was!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

To know which row was last updated, you need to create a new column of type `DATETIME`/`DATETIME2` and update it with a trigger. There is no data type that automatically updates itself with date/time information every time the row is updated.

To avoid recursion you can use the `UPDATE()` clause inside the trigger, e.g.

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.SetLastUpdatedBusiness 
ON dbo.Businesses 
AFTER UPDATE -- not insert!
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT UPDATE(LastUpdated)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE t
            SET t.LastUpdated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -- not dbo.LastUpdated!
            FROM dbo.Businesses AS t -- not b!
            INNER JOIN inserted AS i 
            ON t.ID = i.ID;
    END
END
GO
```

In modern versions you can trick SQL Server into doing this using temporal tables:

- [Maintaining LastModified Without Triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2021/04/01/lastmodified-without-triggers)

But this is full of caveats and limitations and was really only making light of multiple other similar posts:

- [A System-Maintained LastModifiedDate Column](https://michaeljswart.com/2021/10/a-system-maintained-lastmodifieddate-column/)
- [Tracking Row Changes With Temporal
  Columns](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/tracking-row-changes-with-temporal-columns/)
- [How to add “created” and “updated” timestamps without triggers](https://sqlsunday.com/2021/08/09/add-created-and-updated-timestamps/)
- [Need a datetime column that automatically updates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47487144/61305)

Comment: Wasn't me! Even if I had enough points, I wouldn't vote either of these answers down as they were both very helpful. I'm going to try this out and will report back on how I get on.

Comment: Back again...

Just tried this, and it didn't work. I have a table called Businesses, that has a DateTime field called LastUpdated, which is the one I want to be updated every time the row changes. I added the following trigger, but the LastUpdated field wasn't changed when I updated one of the rows.

What did I do wrong? Thanks again.

create trigger SetLastUpdatedBusiness on Businesses after insert as
if not UPDATE(LastUpdated)
begin
  update t
  set dbo.LastUpdated=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
  from Businesses as b
  inner join inserted as i
  on b.ID=i.ID
end
go

Comment: What column did you update? Can you put your trigger and update statement in your question as a code sample, so it is readable? Why is your column reference `dbo.LastUpdated`? That is not a column.

Comment: Also your trigger says `AFTER INSERT` ... I think you meant `AFTER UPDATE`. You also need the aliases to match, you can't say `UPDATE t` and then refer to `Businesses as b` - you need to change one or the other. Please see updated sample.

Comment: Ah, thanks Aaron. I had created the trigger on insert (duh!) instead of update. I guess the wrong aliases didn't help! All working now.

Comment: To be pedantic, "To know which row was last updated..." is wrong isn't it? With this implementation couldn't there be two rows with the same value for LastUpdated?

Comment: @cja sure, that's pretty pedantic. There's always a chance for ties, obviously.

Answer (score 12):

It's not that easy, unfortunately.

You can add a new `DATETIME` (or `DATETIME2`) field to your table, and you can give it a default constraint of `GETDATE()` - that will set the value when a new row is inserted.

Unfortunately, other than creating an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger, there is no "out of the box" way to keep it updated all the time. The trigger per se isn't hard to write, but you'll have to write it for each and every single table that should have that feature.....

Comment: I'd say a trigger qualifies as an automatic way to keep it updated. Doesn't address the endless trigger recursion part of the question.

Comment: @Will Den: yes, it's automatic - once you've written it and put it in place. I have been hoping Microsoft might introduce something similar to the `timestamp/rowversion` columns that is automatically updated by SQL Server itself - but based on human-readable date/time formats. No such luck yet (and SQL Server "Denali" also doesn't seem to have anything like that :-( )