# Date of inserting a row into table 

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to find date+time when a row was inserted into a table in SQL Server 2005?

Does SQL Server log insert commands?

Comment: Why don't you have a `DateTime` column of your own in your table to record this?

Comment: No. There's no way to find this out, unless you have a `DateTime` column on that table that tracks this date+time.

Comment: Please see these other answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720486/date-timestamp-to-record-when-a-record-was-added-to-the-table http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349288/how-do-i-add-a-last-updated-column-in-a-sql-server-2008-r2-table - basically if you want a reliable way to know when a row was inserted, you add a new datetime column with a default of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Comment: I have a column named as "ORDER_DATE", and its default value = GETDATE()
But some insert commands have also ORDER_DATE value and they were wrong. So, some ORDER_DATE values not correct :(

Comment: Well if you explicitly overwrote the default value, you're kind of out of luck. Why is this allowed to happen? Why do any of your INSERT statements mention that column at all?

Answer (score 3):

Whenever I create a table, I alway include the following two columns:

```
CreatedBy varchar(255) default system_name,
CreatedAt datetime default getdate()
```

Although this uses a bit of extra space, I've found that the information proves very, very useful over time.

Your question is about the log.  The answer is "yes".  However, whether you can get the information depends on your recovery mode.  If simple, then the records are overwritten for the next transaction.  If bulk or full, then the information is in the log, at least since the last incremental backup.

Comment: Can you explain how to find out when a row was inserted by reading the log?

Answer (score 2):

You can derive insert date as long as you are using cdc created functions to pull actual data records.

So for example if you will pull something like:

```
DECLARE @from_lsn binary(10), @to_lsn binary(10);                         

SET @from_lsn=sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn ( 'name_of_your_cdc_instance_on_cdc_table' );
SET @to_lsn=sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn();

SELECT * FROM 
cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_name_of_your_cdc_instance_on_cdc_table
(
    @from_lsn, 
    @to_lsn, 
    N'all'
);
```

You can use cdc built in function `sys.fn_cdc_map_lsn_to_time` to convert Log Sequence Number to datetime. Below usecase:

```
SELECT sys.fn_cdc_map_lsn_to_time(__$start_lsn),* FROM 
cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_name_of_your_cdc_instance_on_cdc_table
(
    @from_lsn, 
    @to_lsn, 
    N'all'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can have a InsertDate default getdate() column on your table, that would be the easiest approach.

On SQl Server 2008 you can use [CDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to control changed data on your table

> Change data capture records insert, update, and delete activity that
>   is applied to a SQL Server table. This makes the details of the
>   changes available in an easily consumed relational format. Column
>   information and the metadata that is required to apply the changes to
>   a target environment is captured for the modified rows and stored in
>   change tables that mirror the column structure of the tracked source
>   tables. Table-valued functions are provided to allow systematic access
>   to the change data by consumers.

Comment: Yes, I look for that. But is CDC not available in Sql Server 2005?

Comment: no, I just mentioned it so you know that it exists. I said "On SQl Server 2008 " :)

Comment: Does CDC run defaultly on 2008, or must I set it to run? I can use it Sql Server 2008 Web Edition