# SQL Server query about first and last records

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Is there any way to get the first and last records date in SQL Server like if I have a table with single column and no date column.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834610/date-of-inserting-a-row-into-table it is not possible to find this out without a Date/Time column on the table

Comment: The best way is to add a datetime column.

Comment: Just add a new column to your table called datetime and then populate it automatically, you could do this by having the default as NOW()

Comment: By SQL definitions, tables are an *unordered* bag of rows. The only time it makes sense to talk using positional terms such as first or last is if you've *defined* an order based on one or more of the columns (which usually means you'll need to have those columns in the `ORDER BY` clause of the query in which you're using those positional terms)

Comment: if you have a unique key on the table you might be able to make use of the %%physloc%% to determine this without having a date column, this answer has more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909155/equivalent-of-oracles-rowid-in-sql-server