# sql when set default value getdate(), does it set value when run update statement?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I know when you insert a value into db, it set that column value as current datetime,
does it apply to it when you run a update statement?

e.g.

table schema:

```
Id, Name, CreatedDate(getdate())
```

when i insert into table `id = 1 , name = 'john'` it will set `createdDate = current date`

if i run an update statement

```
update table set name="john2" where id =1
```

Will it update the `createdDate`?

Comment: If you're asking whether there's a simple way to implement a "LastModifiedDateTime" column in a table, then no, there's no simple way for that to work.

Comment: No simple way to implement a "LastModifiedDateTime"? if you have a column for that and then your update for that column contains the value "sysdate" then it is extremely easy. I don't see it being any more difficult than any other update at all.

Comment: @Tony318 the challenge is the OP doesn't want to mention the column in every single update statement. Today this requires a trigger since default constraints don't help updates.

Comment: @Tony318 - it is if you don't want inserters/updaters to have to reference that column and/or specify the value at that time.

Comment: @Kiddo why would you want to update the `createdDate` column when a row is later updated? Shouldn't this be a separate column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wow - hard to understand...

i think NO based on the clues.

if you insert a record with a NULL in a column, and that column has a default value defined, then the default value will be stored instead of null.

update will only update the columns specified in the statement.

UNLESS you have a trigger that does the special logic - in which case, you need to look at the trigger code to know the answer.

Comment: If you insert a row with an explicit `NULL`, it will be set to `NULL` or rejected (if the column doesn't accept nulls). The default will only be used if a) the column isn't included in the column list of the `INSERT`, or b) the keyword `DEFAULT` is in the appropriate position for the column in the `VALUES` clause.

Answer (score 8):

No, a DEFAULT CONSTRAINT is only invoked on INSERT, and only when (a) combined with a NOT NULL constraint or (b) using DEFAULT VALUES. For an UPDATE, SQL Server is not going to look at your DEFAULT CONSTRAINT at all. Currently you need a trigger ( see [How do I add a "last updated" column in a SQL Server 2008 R2 table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349288/how-do-i-add-a-last-updated-column-in-a-sql-server-2008-r2-table) ), but there have been multiple requests for this functionality to be built in.

I've blogged about a way to trick SQL Server into doing this using temporal tables:

- [Maintaining LastModified Without Triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2021/04/01/lastmodified-without-triggers)

But this is full of caveats and limitations and was really only making light of multiple other similar posts:

- [A System-Maintained LastModifiedDate Column](https://michaeljswart.com/2021/10/a-system-maintained-lastmodifieddate-column/)
- [Tracking Row Changes With Temporal
  Columns](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/tracking-row-changes-with-temporal-columns/)
- [How to add “created” and “updated” timestamps without triggers](https://sqlsunday.com/2021/08/09/add-created-and-updated-timestamps/)
- [Need a datetime column that automatically updates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47487144/61305)

Answer (score 1):

if your update statement tell to update a column with getfate() it will, but if you just update a name for example and you have a createdate column (which was inserted with getdate()), this columns wont be affected.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using DEFAULT  constraint like i did it with OrderDate field in below statement.

CREATE TABLE Orders
(
O_Id int NOT NULL,
OrderNo int NOT NULL,
P_Id int,
OrderDate date DEFAULT GETDATE()
)