# Hibernate save the Entity with function "GETDATE()" for last_modified_date

Tags: hibernate, jpa

```
@UpdateTimestamp
private ZonedDateTime last_modified_date;
```

@UpdateTimestamp was added to last_modified_date attribute, and after save and commit, it has value saved into DB column, but my question is that if the transaction is quite long, for example, the last_modified_date is set date value "2019-10-26 10:00:00", but maybe the resource issue, then transaction actually take 20s to commit, those records are flushed to DB at "2019-10-26 10:00:20",but the value of last_modified_date still "2019-10-26 10:00:00"...

we have one tool to sync data base on the last_modified_date every 10 seconds, and this caused lost data, because 10:00:00 to 10:00:10 cannot retrieve the record....

and because I'm using Sqlserver, so my question is can I save the Entity with function "GETDATE()" for last_modified_date?

Comment: Leave it up to the database to handle? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493178/need-a-datetime-field-in-ms-sql-that-automatically-updates-when-the-record-is-mo

Comment: Thanks, my boss said that trigger may cause performance issue, so he didn't take this advice...

Comment: Ask him how he'd address  the problem then.