# Set default date on updating a row in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with ID, City, CreateDate, UpdateDate columns.
Whenever a new row is created, default value is added(this is working as expected). Just like default value for new row, how to set default date when row is updated ie if I update the table(as shown below), UpdateDate should have default value GetDate().

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable 
(
     ID Int, 
     City Varchar(100), 
     CreateDate Datetime, 
     UpdateDate Datetime
);

ALTER TABLE TestTable 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [Constraint_CreateDate] DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR [CreateDate];

INSERT INTO TestTable (ID, City) 
VALUES (1, 'DC');

UPDATE TestTable 
SET City = 'NY' 
WHERE ID = 1; -- How to populate the UpdateDate when this update happen.
```

Comment: You can't specify a default value on an update with a constraint. You'll need to either specify the value in the UPDATE statement or create a trigger to do same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need a datetime field in MS SQL that automatically updates when the record is modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493178/need-a-datetime-field-in-ms-sql-that-automatically-updates-when-the-record-is-mo)

Answer (score 1):

The `DEFAULT` constraint **only** works when inserting a new row, and there's no declarative way to define a default for an update. You'll just have to do this explicitly in your `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE TestTable 
SET City = 'NY',
    UpdateDate = SYSDATETIME()
WHERE ID = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use mixed defaults with a trigger. But the cheapest solution in terms of performance is that of @marc_s.

Solution with trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable 
(
     ID Int, 
     City Varchar(100), 
     CreateDate Datetime default getdate(), 
     UpdateDate Datetime default getdate()
);

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.update_TestTable ON TestTable
AFTER UPDATE 
AS UPDATE TestTable SET UpdateDate = getdate()
   FROM TestTable t INNER JOIN inserted i ON t.ID = i.ID
;

INSERT INTO TestTable (ID, City) 
VALUES (1, 'DC');

select * from TestTable ;

UPDATE TestTable 
SET City = 'NY' 
WHERE ID = 1;

select * from TestTable ;
```

If you want test on line : [test here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a6c5a/1)