# How to update current time stamp in MS SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

What is the equivalent of the following in MS SQL server syntax?

```
CREATE TABLE `new_table` (
  `updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

I have tried:

```
update myTable set updated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: in regards to your edit, with your attempt, that *would* `UPDATE` **every** row in your table; is that intended?

Comment: You can use `GENERATED ALWAYS` in this specific case rather than a trigger with some caveats https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493178/need-a-datetime-column-in-sql-server-that-automatically-updates-when-the-record/47487144#47487144

Comment: Yes, it is intended to updated every row in my table. @Larnu

Comment: Your syntax is not TSQL - are you perhaps using MySQL?

Comment: @SMor yes, they have a MySQL create table statement and they want the equivalent for SQL Server.

Answer (score -2):

Any update on table with timestamp data type will automatically update it's row timestamp value. If anything is missing in your question, please add more data.

Comment: `timestamp` data type is not a date, it's a synonym for `rowversion`

Comment: @Charlieface where did i specify it'a a date?

Comment: OP wants the equivalent of MySQL's `timestamp` which definitely *is* a date

Comment: This reads more like a comment anyway, rather than an answer. Especially as you're asking the OP to edit their question in said answer.