# How to create trigger for whole database in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, timestamp

I have database with 7 tables and every table has these columns:

```
created_at SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
updated_at SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
```

As you can see, when you insert data into a table, it will have default `created_at` and `updated_at` columns.

As I know, it's impossible in SQL Server create autoupdated columns like in MySQL:

```
created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
updated_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

I need to project my database, so, when record is inserted, `updated_at` will be updated.

Of course, I can create just 7 triggers, just like that:

```
CREATE TRIGGER E_U_CTD
ON Cities
FOR UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE T
    SET updated_at = SYSDATETIME()
    FROM CitiesTest AS T
    JOIN inserted AS i ON T.id = i.id;
```

But is there more convenient solution (what if I had 100 tables)?

Comment: Triggers are bound to just one table. There is no way (at least that I know) you can do this with just one trigger. So I am afraid you will need to write 7 triggers (or 100 if you had 100 tables). In my opinion triggers are still the best method for doing this.

Comment: @GuidoG: the only other option would be to do this in your application (app or service layer) using e.g. Entity Framework or something similar, that would ensure the `updated_at` value gets updated each time the data is stored. But then of course, if someone accesses your database bypassing your application code, `updated_at` cannot be updated...

Comment: Yeah, and that's a problem, I need to do that on 'pure' SQL, if it would be application, it would be much easier to implement,

Comment: @marc_s That is not a good option in my opinion, that can be bypassed, a trigger cannot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need a datetime column in SQL Server that automatically updates when the record is modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493178/need-a-datetime-column-in-sql-server-that-automatically-updates-when-the-record) in particular this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47487144/14868997

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is answer. I just took all tables from my DB, iterate them and create trigger on every iteration for every table:

```
DECLARE @Itr INT, @tableName nvarchar(259), @triggerName sysname, @execTrigger nvarchar(max); SET @Itr = 0;
WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SYS.TABLES) > @Itr
BEGIN
    SELECT @tableName = QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(name),
           @triggerName = 'TRIGGER_' + LEFT(name);
            FROM sys.Tables
            ORDER BY name
            OFFSET @Itr ROWS
            FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
        PRINT @tableName;

    SET @execTrigger = 'CREATE TRIGGER ' + @triggerName + ' ON ' + @tableName +
                       ' FOR UPDATE as SET NOCOUNT ON; UPDATE T SET updated_at = GETDATE() ' + ' FROM ' +
                       @tableName + ' AS T JOIN inserted AS i ON T.id = i.id;';
    PRINT @execTrigger
    EXEC(@execTrigger)
    SET @Itr = @Itr + 1;
end
```

Use something like that, if you need!

Comment: You should really lookup the primary key column(s) and join on those, they may not always be `Id`