# Problem with creating trigger. Column names in each table must be unique. MsSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have this trigger which has to work on `CREATE_TABLE` and should check if there is column `updated_at` in table. If not, create one and set another trigger.

This is how it looks like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdatedAtFiled ON DATABASE
    FOR CREATE_TABLE
AS
BEGIN
        DECLARE @createdTableName VARCHAR(50), @column VARCHAR(50), @triggerName VARCHAR(50), @execTrigger VARCHAR(300), @sqlcmd VARCHAR(100), @ColumnWasCreated INT, @Itr INT;
        SET @Itr = 0;
        SET @ColumnWasCreated = 0;
        SELECT @createdTableName = name FROM sys.Tables ORDER BY create_date
        WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @createdTableName) > @Itr
            BEGIN
                SELECT @column = COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @createdTableName ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME OFFSET @Itr ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
                SET @triggerName = 'TRIGGER_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @createdTableName);
                SET @execTrigger = 'CREATE TRIGGER ' + @triggerName + ' ON ' + @createdTableName +
                       ' FOR UPDATE as UPDATE T SET updated_at = GETDATE() ' + ' FROM ' +
                       @createdTableName + ' AS T JOIN inserted AS i ON T.id = i.id;';
                IF (@column != 'updated_at' AND @ColumnWasCreated <= 0)
                    SET @sqlcmd = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @createdTableName + ' ADD updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()';
                    EXEC(@sqlcmd)
                    EXEC(@execTrigger)
                SET @ColumnWasCreated = 1;
                SET @Itr = @Itr + 1;
            END
END
```

And every time I create table I get an error:

```
CREATE TABLE test(id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1), name VARCHAR(20))
```

> [S0004][2705] Line 1: Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'updated_at' in table 'test' is specified more than once.`

I guess, there is problem in this conditional, but I'm not sure:

`IF (@column != 'updated_at' AND @ColumnWasCreated <= 0)`

I literally can't find the error. What's wrong? How can I fix that?

Comment: This is almost certainly an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info). With respect, the above logic has no right being in a `TRIGGER`. A `TRIGGER` should have as *minimal* impact as possible, and yet you have a `WHILE`, *and* dynamic SQL. That dynamic SQL is also quite open to injection. What are you *really* trying to achieve here?

Comment: I agree with Larnu. As for the error, most likely it's because your INSERTED table also will contain an updated_at column. Try changing to `SET T.updated_at`. If all you are trying to achieve, though, is adding an `updated_at` column to every table, do not use a trigger for that, but rather a while loop by itself. A trigger will fire for every update. If you need `updated_at` to be updated whenever a row is modified, do so within the UPDATE statement.

Comment: Aside from the fact that this really doesn't seem like a good idea, using the `created_date` on `sys.tables` is the wrong way to identify the table that was created. Instead, use [the `EVENTDATA` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eventdata-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to select the schema name and table name.

Comment: `SELECT @SchemaName = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]', 'sysname'), @TableName = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'sysname');`

Comment: You'll also want to check that the table contains a column called `id` before trying to create a trigger that joins the table to the `inserted` table on that column.

Comment: Yes it is an XY problem and you cannot do it into a DDL trigger. Use a scheduled job that analyze asynchronnously new created tables.

Comment: Just one more thing, it seems your code assumes that `IF` somehow applies to all subsequent statements until the next (unrelated) `END`. Basically, you should start over and think about what actual problem you're trying to solve, because no matter what that problem is, _this_ is not the solution.

Comment: @Larnu The `WHILE` loop is within the DDL trigger, so it's unlikely to have a big impact. Probably still wrong to do though

Answer (score 0):

**I will preface this by saying that I think using a trigger for this is a bad idea.** There are [a number of other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47487144/14868997) to this, not least just making sure you do this correctly for each table in the first place.

Be that as it may:

- You should specify the schema name everywhere.
- Don't pull the most recent table from `sys.tables`, instead use `EVENTDATA` to get the info which relates to the particular `CREATE TABLE` command that was executed.
- Object names can be up to `nvarchar(128)`, you can use the alias `sysname`
- Use `QUOTENAME` to quote object names correctly.
- The DML trigger needs to join on the primary key, which may not be `id` and may be more than one column.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER UpdatedAtFiled ON DATABASE
    FOR CREATE_TABLE
AS

DECLARE @tableName sysname = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]','sysname');
DECLARE @schemaName sysname = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]','sysname');

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
    WHERE s.name = @schemaName
      AND t.name = @tableName
      AND c.name = 'updated_at')
BEGIN
    SET @sql = '
ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + '
   ADD updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE();
';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END

SET @sql = '
CREATE TRIGGER ' + QUOTENAME('TRIGGER_' + @tableName) + ' ON ' + QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + '
FOR UPDATE AS

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    RETURN;

UPDATE T
SET updated_at = GETDATE()
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ' AS T
JOIN inserted AS i ON ('
  + (
    SELECT STRING_AGG('T.' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' = i.' + QUOTENAME(c.name),  ' AND ')
    FROM sys.tables t
    JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
    JOIN sys.indexes i ON i.object_id = t.object_id
    JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = i.object_id
                             AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
    JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
                      AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
    WHERE i.is_primary_key = 1
      AND ic.is_included_column = 0
)
  + ');
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

GO
```