# the best approach to save CreatedOn and ModifiedOn in EFCore?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

what would be the best approach to update datetime when an entity is created or updated?
I'm using this approach, any idea about the pros & cons?

```
    public interface ITimeAudit
    {
        public DateTimeOffset CreatedOn { get; }
        public DateTimeOffset ModifiedOn { get; }
        void UpdateModifiedOn();
    }
```

in my entities I inherite ITimeAudit.
then I override save changes in dbContext.

```
        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            SetProperties();
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }

private void SetProperties()
        {
            foreach (var entity in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Modified))
            {
                if (entity.Entity is ITimeAudit updated)
                {
                    updated.UpdateModifiedOn();
                }
            }
           //and a logic for created
        }
```

Comment: I do something very similar in a lot of projects, and it works well. As for cons: the value won't be updated if someone pokes around directly in the SQL database rather than using the `DbContext`; and it may not be immediately obvious to someone else where these "magic" values come from.

Comment: Another option may be to use SQL Server 2016's [temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15), which would give you a much more detailed audit log of changes to your entities. Or you can use [`PERIOD FOR` without a history table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47487144/124386) to have the system update the `ModifiedOn` column every time the record is updated.

Comment: Looks like a good approach. You can always go 'old school' and just set the modified / created by when you do that in the controller. And I would use some Audit stuff like that it https://entityframework-extensions.net/ if you wanted more detail. But yeah good approach