# how to check if table in mssql had been modified

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

What it's the fastest way to check if table or row in mssql(using nodejs) has been modified?

I need to check if my db had been updated in the last 30 min.

if it's not has been updated in the last 30 min, i will send an email to the client with a lead.

Comment: You can do it via SQL. But what is the exact use case? It seems to me, that there could be a better way.

Comment: For a table you can use `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`. For a *row* that might require your own implementation, possibly *system_versioning*.

Comment: The best way in my mind is that you need to specify a field for user model, for instance `lastUpdate`. And store current timestamp in it,  anytime something related to that user is updated. After that, regularly check this field, for instance each 5 minutes. If the value of this field tells you that more than 30 mins has passed since last update, send an email.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need a datetime column in SQL Server that automatically updates when the record is modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493178/need-a-datetime-column-in-sql-server-that-automatically-updates-when-the-record) in particular this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47487144/14868997

Answer (score 0):

You could add "created_at" and "modified_at" columns to your table. Then you just update "modified_at" everytime you make changes to your data. Now you have updated information about when this data was modified.

Now if you want to check if there are any modifications in any records in the last 30 minutes you could create cronjob that runs certain query. I don't have any example query because I am not so good in SQL. But now you can get started with this information.

Comment: It is not an efficient way cause each time it needs to check every single row related to a user, say thousands, to see if any change has happened.

Comment: Right. How about adding an index to that column and then SELECT with ORDER BY and LIMIT 1 to retrieve the most recent change? But it seems the user wanted to know when a particular row has been updated too, so then this is the way to go. Unfortunately, we do not know if the table modification is external or within the same system. If it is external and needs to be detected, then another approach would be required, like copying the whole table at each scan.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the following function to find the last time any update was done against a table:

```
create function dbo.TableLastUpdated(@schema sysname, @name sysname)
returns datetime as
begin
return (
    select Max(last_user_update) 
    from sys.tables t
    join sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats s on s.object_id = t.object_id
    where t.name = @name and t.schema_id=Schema_Id(@schema)
)
end
```

Then simply use it

```
select dbo.TableLastUpdated('dbo','Table Name')
```

Note this information is only available since the last time the server was started.