# Retrieve records from table without timestamp column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, amazon-rds, change-tracking

I am using AWS RDS SQL Server as my DB. I have a few tables without a timestamp column and need to query those tables for data inserted within the last hour or so. I can't add extra columns, create trigger or change source in any way. Change Tracking (CT) feature of SQL server seems the way to go but I wanted to know is there any other way.

Comment: i don't know any such functionality, but a system must be changeable to go with the time

Comment: A `rowversion` column, although it won't tell you an actual time, you just need to keep track of `MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION()` each time you query. Or you could use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47487144/14868997

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I have asked the Admins if the changes can be done