# Deadlock when trigger is being triggered

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I have a simple trigger that is to update the modifiedtime column when the record have been changed (Updated or Inserted)

However i the server keeps going into a deadlock

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateDatetime
ON Table1
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   UPDATE Table1
   SET LastModified = GETDATE()
   FROM INSERTED i
   WHERE i.ID = Table1.ID
   SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END
```

MSSQL Server is not overly busy, but it can update / insert on Table1 maybe 10 transactions a minute.

Comment: What is the deadlock graph? table definition including indexes? execution plan? [PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47487144/73226) would be another way of doing this BTW

Comment: The trigger will be executed within the transaction of the queries modifying the table. Is the deadlock between two sessions running the same query? two different queries? What are the query(ies) involved? Can you share details of the table schema and the deadlock graph?

Comment: Do you have a unique index on `id`? @IMSoP recursive triggers are disabled by default in sql server, so it's unlikely to be this (most people don't enable recursive triggers), besides, if this was the issue the OP would be hitting max recursion errors (but the instead of insert/update suggestion is still reasonable).

Comment: By the way, SQL Server does not have BEFORE-triggers

Comment: OK, thanks both. It was a bit of a guess, I admit. I'm not super-familiar with SQL Server's triggers in particular.

Comment: @IMSoP for future reference what you know as a `before` trigger is known as an `instead of` in SQL Server ("instead of" because inside the trigger you are free to do anything, including foregoing the original DML and redirecting to an entirely different table, or doing nothing at all, or, per your suggestion, modifying the incoming rows and then proceeding against the original table)

Comment: Is `Id` the clsuetering key? Indeed there are much better solutions, such as setting `LastModified` in the insert or update statement in the first place, or using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47487144/14868997) written by @MartinSmith himself.