# Can I determine when a Azure SQL DB row was last updated?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Edit: This is not a question about how to implement a scheme to track when database rows have been updated. I know how to do that. It is about how to establish when one particular tennant in a multi-tennant database last made an update with no such scheme in place! As I said in my question, I don't think there is any way to do this but my boss insists that a predecessor of mine managed to do it. I think he is mis-remembering.
End of edit.

Original question:
I don't think there is any way to do this, but my boss recalls it being done in the past.

We have a multi-tennant Azure SQL DB. We do not track when rows were created or last updated. We don't use change tracking. We don't use auditing. He wants to know when a user belonging to a specific organisation last updated any data. Rows have an OrganisationID to identify the organisation they belong to.

I know I can find when a table was last updated, but I don't believe that I can determine when rows were last updated. Am I correct?

Comment: Azure SQL Databases, nor SQL Server, log this information by default, no. If you want to store the last time a row was updated, you should either have a column to denote this and ensure it is `UPDATE`d via your procedures, or consider (like you mentioned) change tracking or perhaps even a temporal table.

Comment: You can find info regarding the last update at the object level, no such info is available at the record/row level.

Comment: Besides temporal tables and CT/CDC, you can also use a trigger to roll your own audit trail of when a row changed.

Comment: Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47487144/14868997) is probably the best